# Touch Coordinates from UIPanGestureRecognizer

Tags: ios, touch, uigesturerecognizer

Is it possible to get the absolute touch coordinates from [UIPanGestureRecognizer translationInView]? I'm working on an iPad app and have been searching a lot to get the touch coordinate values from UIPanGestureRecognizer!

I've also tried offsetting using the values we get from transaltionInView but I'm not really able to comprehend the math behind it...

Any suggestions guys?

Ravi

Answer (score 18, accepted):

`translationInView` is the delta change of a gesture. If you move your finger to the left by 20 pt, you'll get `(-20.0, 0.0)`, it's already "absolute" in that sense.

What you probably mean is that you want the `locationInView`, which relative to the view handed through the argument, even if said view is not the one recognizing the events. Typically, you would hand the view of the view controller, or the view that will take care of the event, or the subview which makes more sense to your implementation.

Also, keep in mind, if you need the real absolute, you can hand `nil` through the arguments, and it returns it relative to the window (aka. "absolute")

And, if you need to do logic with other views, you can convert the coordinate from one view to another with the `UIView` instance methods: `convertRect:fromView:`, `convertRect:toView:`, `convertPoint:fromView:`, `convertPoint:toView:`. These methods also accept `nil` as the view argument to mean "absolute" to the window.

Comment: Awesome! I completely missed the point that these gestures are derived from UIGestureRecognizer! Once again, thanks a lot!

Comment: @Can According to the docs `translationInView:` gives the total movement, not the delta movement.

Comment: @Jonathan. One year late, but I fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an easier way:

```
gesture.locationInView(myView)
```

Returns the point computed as the location in a given view of the gesture represented by the receive as CGPoint.

Comment: Can you elaborate a bit more on what this does and how it's different from what the OP already tried?  Does it return a `CGPoint`?